# How do I use the tab key in bash to expand aliases (while keeping the current tab functionality)

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I have these:

```
alias nuke-gently="rm -rf"
alias ng="nuke-gently"
```

in my `.bash_profile`. (`nuke` also points to a script that runs `sudo rm -rf` with some protections against `/` and `~` and stuff)

What I want to happen is:

type: `ng`
press: `<tab>`
see: `ng` replaced with `nuke-gently`

I know this can be done with Ctrl + Alt + e, but that kinda defeats the purpose of my two letter alias.

Is there a way to of tab run Ctrl + Alt + e for `ng`? while keeping the existing tab-completion for everything else?

Comment: Why do you need to expand it? One purpose of an alias is to avoid unnecessary typing, so `ng {parameters}` will run what you want without the extra `Tab` key-stroke. Also, it would be better to define `alias ng="rm -rf"` directly.

Comment: you're not wrong, but: because I think the phrasing is funny, and it would be fun to have if I needed to rm -rf something during a presentation / talk / lunch'n'learn

Comment: I too want this functionality like zsh has but when I'm forced to use bash on a server.

Answer (score 1):

Place it on SHIFT + Tab. That's what i did.

Put the following line into your "~/.inputrc":

```
"\e[Z":          "SHIFT-TAB"
"SHIFT-TAB":      history-and-alias-expand-line
```

Now you can complete with `Tab` and resolve with `Shift + Tab`.
It's absolutely comfortable and works.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work using `bind`

Comment: @SridharSarnobat Open your terminal emulator, press ctrl and then v. Press shift and then tab. Take the output instead of mine for the shift-tab entry. For how to use it with the bind command i have to check later.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat Ok, i looked it up. Use the following command: `bind '"\e[Z":history-and-alias-expand-line'` and don't forget to put it in your `.bashrc` to make it permanent.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. I'd give up on it. Ideally I'd like to use just tab like zsh can but that's probably asking too much of bash.